# Query Over Oracle DB Link Requiring global_name = true

Tags: oracle, catalog-views

I'm running the following queries over a private dblink (Oracle Database 19c):

```
delete from myschema.mytable@mydblink where SERVER = (select host_name from gv$instance);
insert into myschema.mytable@mydblink
select * from
( 
    select * from
    (
        SELECT 
            (select instance_name from gv$instance) as DB,
            (select host_name from gv$instance) as SERVER,
            to_char(SESSION_KEY) as SESSIONKEY,
            INPUT_TYPE as INPUTTYPE,
            STATUS,
            TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') as STARTTIME,
            TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') as ENDTIME,
--            time_taken_display as TIMETAKEN,
--            output_bytes_display as OUTPUTBYTES,
--            output_bytes_per_sec_display as OUTPUTBPS,
            1 as ORDERDUMMY
        FROM V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS where end_time > sysdate - 3
        union
        select
            (select instance_name from gv$instance) as DB,
            (select host_name from gv$instance) as SERVER,
            'has' as SESSIONKEY,
            'no' as INPUTTYPE,
            'recent' as STATUS,
            'results' as STARTTIME,
            null as ENDTIME,
--            null as TIMETAKEN,
--            null as OUTPUTBYTES,
--            null as OUTPUTBPS,
            2 as ORDERDUMMY
        from dual
    )
    order by orderdummy fetch first 1 row with ties
);
commit;
```

They work just fine to delete, insert, and commit the data like I want it to.
The problem arises when I uncomment any one of the three column pairs.  For example, if I uncomment the two TIMETAKEN lines (target table adjusted to match column needs), the query errors with:

> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation
> 02069. 00000 -  "global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation"
> *Cause:    A remote mapping of the statement is required but cannot be achieved
> because global_names should be set to TRUE for it to be achieved
> *Action:   Issue alter session set global_names = true if possible

Setting global_names = true does not help because the dblink name doesn't match the db name.  I'd like to understand why the query works fine until I try to add any one of these three columns to the query...

```
*time_taken_display
*output_bytes_display
*output_bytes_per_sec_display
```

For what it's worth, I tried removing the end_time column and leaving time_taken_display in, and it errored out the same way, indicating time_taken_display being the culprit.

As usual, the Oracle documentation I found on global_names wasn't much help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Ora-02069 When Using a Local Function While Updating a Remote Table (Doc ID 342320.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=342320.1)

You need a valid support contract associated with your Oracle account to be able to view the above.

Here is an unofficial version:

http://lintzyuan.blogspot.com/2014/10/procedure-remote-database-dml-ora-2069.html

> Because of a limitation, it is not possible to use a local function
> when doing a dml operation on a remote table .When this is attempted,
> the ora-2069 is raised.

You can check the definition of `V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS` in `V$FIXED_TABLE_DEFINITON`. The columns you listed are function calls:

```
...
sys.dbms_rcvman.num2displaysize(output_bytes)  output_bytes_display,
...
sys.dbms_rcvman.num2displaysize(output_bytes_per_sec)          output_bytes_per_sec_display,
...
sys.dbms_rcvman.sec2displaytime(elapsed_seconds) time_taken_display,
...
```

Solution from above link:

> These are possible workaround to avoid the ora-2069 error in the
> described scenario
>
> 1. Use global_names=true.  This can be done on a session basis: "alter
>    session set global_names=true".  If you are having problems getting this
>    to work, it is no doubt a configuration problem.  Please open a separate
>    TAR for this if you can't figure it out.
> 2. Put the function to be used at the remote site.
> 3. Put a wrapper function at the remote site which calls the actual function
>    over a database link back to the local site.
> 4. Include in the "from" the "dual" table. You'll have a Cartesian product (with dual) and the functions will be applied in the calling
>    side, hence some performance issues can be raised.

Comment: Thanks for that info!  Looks like we want `V$FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION`, though.  At least in 19c, `V$FIXED_TABLE_DEFINITON` doesn't seem to be a valid view.